# Measuring Ethernet Impedance

Tags: pcb-design, ethernet

I have a PCB, which was not designed by me. The Ethernet works intermittently between multiple copies, except for on one, where it works just fine.

I want to start troubleshooting at layer 1, and when I looked at the design for this PCB, I noticed that there is no impedance control, or length matching on the traces going from the RJ45 to the PHY (which is integrated into the microcontroller). These traces are routed like GPIO, not like a differential pair. There is also no ground plane on this board, so calculating the actual impedance if the traces is going to be very difficult.

I suspect there is a signal integrity issue that is causing the ethernet to work intermittently, but how do I go about proving it? I was thinking of using my VNA and measuring the traces individually (single ended), but I was hoping to get some different ideas from this post.

The ethernet jack in question: [Mouser Link](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/WIZnet/RB1-125BAG1A?qs=K8aI8m0%252Bj2HL3CgJHC4yWQ%3D%3D)

So, I did end up hooking my VNA up to the boards, and here is the results I got. Note this was on raw boards, no RJ45 or MCU attached. Measured at 66MHz.

| Line | Resistance | Reactance | SWR | Smith Chart | Delay | Complex |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TX+ | 16.1Ω | -64.2Ω | 7.2 | 16.0Ω 37.2pF | 4.0ns | .21-j.75 |
| TX- | 18.3Ω | -64.2Ω | 8.5 | 18.3Ω 38.4pF | 4.2ns | .19-j.76 |
| RX+ | 16.5Ω | -62.0Ω | 7.7 | 16.5Ω 39.2pF | 4.0ns | .19-j.75 |
| RX- | 15.8Ω | -64.0Ω | 8.5 | 15.7Ω 37.5pF | 4.0ns | .20-j.75 |

[image: Gerber Front/Back]

[image: Ethernet TX+- RX+- Highlighted]

Comment: Do you have a photo of the board?  That would be very helpful.  When you say it's intermittent, could you characterise that? For example "works for an hour then stops for two", or "only one frame in three goes through"?

Comment: Maybe start from the easier end. Sure that might be the problem or.at least a part of it, but looking at the schematics is the first thing, it might not even be that bad but the chip may be handled poorly or power supplies are poor. Is there a magjack or separate transformer on Ethernet?

Comment: @jonathanjo Edited to add images, when I say intermittent, I mean I can usually ping it, but not always. It would probably be a decent idea to run wireshark against it if the problem isn't in layer 1/2.

Comment: What speed ethernet are you using, do you have a datasheet for the PHY?  "Can usually ping" sounds pretty long timescales: have you checked, in particular, any ARP issues or ether address clashes?

Comment: There is no way that connector can match with the PCB pinout so that it will fit or work. The markings are unclear though, but can you post the schematics. Also what MCU is that? Important to know.

Comment: @jonathanjo My boss ran wireshark against it and didn't find anything interesting happening

Comment: @Justme W7500P https://www.wiznet.io/product-item/w7500p/, phy is integrated, and the datasheet for it is linked on that page as well

Comment: @Shaken_U Well I was going to say you are missing termination resistors. But apparently they are inside the W7500P. They still may be software controlled so they need to be enabled in the firmware. And you need to double check which exact connector you have - that can't be the correct magjack/connector type you stated. Please post correct connector type.

Comment: @Justme 
RB1-125BAG1A is the connector

Comment: Measuring the traces as single ended does not tell you the differential impedance. A more useful thing to do would be to verify if the internal terminations are enabled. Measure with oscilloscope to verify that waveforms have correct amplitude so they are not unterminated.